# SQL server - climb up in the tree structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I have some sql table, named Object, which saves tree data in fields ObjectID, ParentID, and others. I have implemented recurse procedure, which select everything down by objectID from tree, like this:

```
1.
1.1.
1.2.
1.2.1.
...
```

Now o need to "Climb up" - by some ObjectID i need to select everything Up, like this:

```
1.2.1.
1.2.
1.
```

How i can do that?

In example, my "down" procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Object_SelectDownByRoot_Simple]
@ObjectID int

AS
WITH tree (ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode) AS
(
    SELECT  ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode
     FROM dbo.[ObjectQ] ofs
     WHERE( ObjectID = @ObjectID )

     UNION ALL

     SELECT     ofs.ObjectID, ofs.ParentID, ofs.ObjectName, ofs.ObjectCode
      FROM dbo.[ObjectQ] ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ObjectID = ofs.ParentID
)

SELECT  
ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode
FROM tree
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Microsoft SQL Server 2005? 2008?

Try something like this;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getParentIDs
ID as int,
level as int
AS
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE getParentIDs
ID as int,
level as int
AS

DECLARE @P as int /* <-- change to your ObjectID datatype */

SELECT @P=ParentID FROM tree WHERE ObjectID = ID

SELECT @P, level
UNION ALL
getParentIDs , 1+level   /* <-- this might not work... :-/ */
GO
```

Comment: This does not work, i get the error list:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getParentIDs, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getParentIDs, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getParentIDs, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'getParentIDs'.